# How to select two object in dictionary in python

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionary:

```py
lst = [{'id': 449, 'created_at': '2021-06-02T11:01:43Z', 'process_status': 3},
 {'id': 453, 'created_at': '2021-06-02T14:41:42Z', 'process_status': 3},
 {'id': 477, 'created_at': '2021-06-03T13:34:13Z', 'process_status': 3}]
```

And I want to choose two object from it.

Also I tried this but not working:

```py
filter_for_invoice_id = [object['created_at'] and object['id'] for object in lst if object['process_status'] == 3]
```

If i want to select only one object it's work pretty good but with more than one object it's not working

Comment: The third item(dict) in the list has no key ' process_status' , So the list comprehension will fail. re-write it as follows, filter_for_invoice_id = [object['created_at'] and object['id'] for object in lst if object.get('process_status') == 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following statement too if you need the output as a list of list. Do note that if there is no `process_status` value, it will throw an error, you will need to handle that separately.

```
filter_for_invoice_id = [[object['created_at'], object['id']] for object in lst if object['process_status'] == 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you do not want to select "object" but rather properties, or pairs, that would look like

```
filter_for_invoice_id = [{'created_at': o['created_at'], 'id': o['id']}
                         for o in lst if o.get('process_status') == 3]
```

---

But is there is more, you may use a second level iteration, with a given list of keys to keep

```
lst = [{'id': 449, 'created_at': '2021-06-02T11:01:43Z', 'process_status': 0},
       {'id': 453, 'created_at': '2021-06-02T14:41:42Z', 'process_status': 3},
       {'id': 477, 'created_at': '2021-06-03T13:34:13Z'}]

keys = {'created_at', 'id'}
filter_for_invoice_id = [{k: o[k] for k in keys} for o in lst if o.get('process_status') == 3]
print(filter_for_invoice_id)  # [{'created_at': '2021-06-02T14:41:42Z', 'id': 453}]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly you want to select one or more objects from `lst` based on a condition.

The simplest way to go about it is this:

`filter_for_invoice_id = [item for item in lst if item['process_status'] == 3]`

Also, I would not recommend using `object` as a variable name as it is a reserved word in Python.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
    lst = [{'id': 449, 'created_at': '2021-06-02T11:01:43Z', 'process_status': 0},
           {'id': 453, 'created_at': '2021-06-02T14:41:42Z', 'process_status': 0},
           {'id': 477, 'created_at': '2021-06-03T13:34:13Z', 'process_status': 3}]
    
    filter_for_invoice_id = [(object['created_at'], object['id'])
                             for object in lst if object['process_status'] == 3]
    
    print(filter_for_invoice_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not want to tell you what's wrong with your code.
You can test this one:

```
dic = {'id': 453, 'created_at': '2021-06-02T14:41:42Z', 'process_status': 3}
print(dic['id'])
print(dic['id'] and dic['created_at'])
print(dic.get('do_not_exists') and dic['created_at'])
```